# Firebase - Register user using Phone Number and OTP and Sign In using Phone Number and user set password

Tags: android, authentication, firebase, firebase-authentication

I am trying to make an android app in which:

**Registration Process (for new users):**

Step 1: Request the user for his mobile number.

Step 2: Send the user an **OTP for verification** of mobile number.

Step 3: If the user has been verified using the OTP, then user is taken to 
another activity where the user has to feed in his details along with the **PASSWORD** he wants to set for his account.

Step 4: The new user gets created.

**Login Process(for pre-existing users):**

Step 1: Request the user for his **mobile number** and his **password**.

Step 2: If the user has entered the correct number and password, then the user is logged in into the app.

**The main problem I am facing is that Firebase does not handle login using Mobile Number and Password both. AFAIK, Firebase logins a Mobile number user only through OTP verification. So how do i login my user using a password rather than an OTP**

Comment: Firebase uses it that way to reduce the hassle of the user. OTP is a kind of password which is verified once sent. Why you need to use the password with it ? If you wish to use the password you can use custom authentication by firebase.